# Access denied when trying to delete a folder on Window VM

Tags: windows, batch-file

This is a strange problem I am facing today. Yesterday, I logged into Windows VM and tried running a simple batch script which deletes an exe if it exists.

```
     IF Exist "C:\Temp\installer.exe" del installer.exe
```

It worked fine yesterday. Today, I came and logged in as same user and tried executing this batch script, it says "Access is denied." I tried with most of the switches like /f, /Q but of no use. And moreover when I tried deleting it manually, it required admin rights today. But yesterday, I could delete the same exe 100 of times using that simple script. Could anyone explain this strange behavior and the solution to this.

Thanks.
Kriti

Answer (score 1):

I know a solution that often works: [take ownership](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/quick-tip-take-ownership-of-files-and-folders-in-windows/)

I don't know how this happens but this might solve your problem for now!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you mistakenly launched the executable and it was running - hence the 'access denied'.